# python import spams：ImportError: No module named _spams_wrap

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

I have installed altas and blas before installing spams-python，when I test spams，there is an error：no moudle named _spams_wrap. I have tried spams-2.5 and spams-2.6,the same. The following is the error info.

In [9]: import spams:

---

```
ImportError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2eecc34cc6d3> in <module>()
----> 1 import spams

/home/liuna/src/spams-2.6.1/spams.py in <module>()
  7 import six.moves
  8
----> 9 import spams_wrap
 10 import numpy as np
 11 import scipy.sparse as ssp

/home/liuna/src/spams-2.6.1/spams_wrap.py in <module>()
 22         except ImportError:
 23             return importlib.import_module('_spams_wrap')
---> 24     _spams_wrap = swig_import_helper()
 25     del swig_import_helper
 26 elif _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 6, 0):

/home/liuna/src/spams-2.6.1/spams_wrap.py in swig_import_helper()
 21             return importlib.import_module(mname)
 22         except ImportError:
---> 23             return importlib.import_module('_spams_wrap')
 24     _spams_wrap = swig_import_helper()
 25     del swig_import_helper

/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.pyc in import_module(name, package)
 35             level += 1
 36         name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
---> 37     __import__(name)
 38     return sys.modules[name]

**ImportError: No module named _spams_wrap**
```